Go file server doesn't serve folder
I am building a website with Golang, HTML, JS and CSS.
Here is my folder structure:
/data
    (Go files that contain data initialization)
/handler
    (Go files for HTTP handling)
/model
    (Go files that include model structs)
/static
    /css 
    /images 
    /js
    /webfonts
/template
    /elements
    /pages
    /sections
main.go
go.mod
go.sum

I initialize the data in data package by calling it from the main() function at the beginning. Here is my data.Initialize() function:
func Initialize() {
    log.Println("Site data is initializing:")
    serveStaticFiles()
    log.Println("Static files are ready!")
    parseTemplates()
    log.Println("Templates are ready!")
    initializeTestimonials()
    initializeHomePageData()
    log.Println("Home page data is ready!")
    initializeAboutPageData()
    log.Println("About page data is ready!")
    initializeContactPageData()
    log.Println("Contact page data is ready!")
    initializeNotFoundPageData()
    log.Println("404 page data is ready!")
}

Here is my serveStaticFiles() function which is inside of data package:
func serveStaticFiles() {
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))
    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs))
}

I call data.Initialize() from the main() function as the first thing:
func main() {
    data.Initialize()

    mux := http.NewServeMux()

    mux.HandleFunc("/", handler.HomeHandler)
    mux.HandleFunc("/home", handler.HomeHandler)
    mux.HandleFunc("/about", handler.AboutHandler)
    mux.HandleFunc("/contact", handler.ContactHandler)
    mux.HandleFunc("/404", handler.NotFoundHandler)

    log.Println("Starting server on :8080")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", mux)
}

However, the files under /static directory don't appear on the browser, returning 404 code.

I have also tried different things with serveStaticFiles() function such as http.Dir("./static"). Nothing seems working. I tried to serve the same folder with Python and it did work. I tried different ports and it seems only the ones that are started from Golang aren't working. os.Getwd() returns the root folder of the project which is where main.go file is.
I appreciate if anyone has an idea. Thanks.

Do you start your server from the root directory of your project, that is from the same directory where main.go lives?

it's not only about main.go, it is also about what is the current working directory when you run your program. Check the value of os.Getwd() when you start your server.

I start it from the root directory since main.go is located there. @MarkusWMahlberg

os.Getwd() returns the root folder of the project which is where main.go file is. @LeGEC

You log that you listen to port 8080 but the code says 8000. Are you sure you’re talking to the right server?

Hi, @Biffen. Thank you for bringing it to my attention. I was trying it on different ports so I forgot to change it again. This parameter doesn't affect the result.

After trying different solutions, I found the problem. I was serving my web pages through a mux object while serving files on an http file server. Now I am serving web pages through http.HandleFunc(). The problem is fixed and the website is working properly. Here is the new main() function:
func main() {
    data.Initialize()

    http.HandleFunc("/", handler.HomeHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/home", handler.HomeHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/about", handler.AboutHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/contact", handler.ContactHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/404", handler.NotFoundHandler)

    log.Println("Starting server on :8080")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

